# Error while installing Google Cloud Tools Plugin 1.6.1 in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7 on Windows 8.1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am unable to install the latest version of Google Cloud Tools Plugin (1.6.1) from Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) on my Windows 8.1 machine. Apparently, the plugin tries to create deep directories and files which span path lengths greater than 260 characters which are not supported in Windows and so this causes the error. Is there any solution to this issue?

```
[Installing Google Cloud SDK app extensions for Java]


Your current Cloud SDK version is: 202.0.0
Installing components from version: 202.0.0

+----------------------------------------------------+
|        These components will be installed.         |
+------------------------------+---------+-----------+
|             Name             | Version |    Size   |
+------------------------------+---------+-----------+
| gRPC python library          |         |           |
| gRPC python library          |   1.9.1 |   7.3 MiB |
| gcloud app Java Extensions   |  1.9.63 | 118.9 MiB |
| gcloud app Python Extensions |  1.9.70 |   6.1 MiB |
+------------------------------+---------+-----------+

For the latest full release notes, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

#============================================================#
#= Creating update staging area                             =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gRPC python library                          =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gRPC python library                          =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gcloud app Java Extensions                   =#
#============================================================#
ERROR: gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\user_dir\\AppData\\Local\\google-cloud-tools-java\\managed-cloud-sdk\\LATEST\\google-cloud-sdk.staging\\platform\\google_appengine\\google\\appengine\\tools\\java\\jetty93\\jetty-distribution\\lib\\apache-jsp\\org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.18.v20170406-nolog.jar'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've unfortunately hit the [dreaded MAX_PATH problem on Windows](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-plugins-core/issues/595) which limits total path lengths to 259 characters plus a NUL byte.  The next release of Cloud Tools for Eclipse will place this auto-installed Cloud SDK in a different location to bring path lengths to less than 259 characters.  In the mean time [there are two workarounds](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3065#issuecomment-390278252) (copied here):

1. Microsoft have a [documented method for enabling long pathnames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) requiring a small change to the Windows registry (search for `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled`).  We're not sure if there is any negative consequence in making this change.
2. You can manually install the Google Cloud SDK in a different location (e.g., `D:\SDK`) so that you won't hit the `MAX_PATH` limit.  Then configure Cloud Tools for Eclipse to use this location in *Preferences > Google Cloud Tools > Google Cloud SDK Location > Choose SDK*.